# Authentication in laravel from details stored in database

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.3

I tried authenticating user from username and password store in database from backend not the one saved after registering from frontend(I mean user registered from URL/register). I have uncommented the Providers database driver section like this:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'users',
    ],
```

And here is the very strange thing that happens. I cant log in the user ffrom the username and password stored manually from backend. But i can log in from registered one. And after once i log in from registered one then i can log in from stored username and password. Can anyone help. I am trying it for the first time and actually i am doing it for multiple authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Did you encrypt the password by `bcrypt` command?

You should use it to hash the password

Comment: yeah i did it via tinker like this : 
C:\xampp\htdocs\regularly>php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.8.0 (PHP 7.0.9 ΓÇö cli) by Justin Hileman
New version is available (current: v0.8.0, latest: v0.8.3)
>>> $admin=new App\Admin
=> App\Admin {#743}
>>> $admin->name="suzan"
=> "suzan"
>>> $admin->email="suzan@email.com"
=> "suzan@email.com"
>>> $admin->password=Hash::make('password')
=> "$2y$10$W3pyZ377XTelDHqRVJrTHekXuJm0H7H5x1GmMn4R0qUKBmMf0yPJ2"
>>> $admin->job_title="teacher"
=> "teacher"
>>> $admin->save()
=> true
>>>

Comment: You add 2 provider with the same name `users`, change the second one (Ex.: database) maybe this is the issue.

Comment: providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'users-db' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'users',
        ],I changed to it but didnt help. First i must be logged in from the registered one then only i can log in with stored one.

Comment: What I understand:
before you changed the configuration: manual => not working, register working.
After: manual => working , registered => not working.


I think only old user was registered by register form will not work, you should change the password of it, did you try to register new users from registration form?

Comment: yes it works fine. I mean new user can be registered. What i wanted is i need to log in from the username and password stored in database . Not only with the registered users. How can i do that?

Comment: you mean login manually in the code? if yes you can use `Auth::loginUsingId()` to login by user ID, or  `Auth::login($user_model)`